# how to show entire report in single page using Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am using MS Report builder 3.0 to create one of my report.The report is the tabular report and sometimes the size of table grows long about 2 to 3 pages.
But i want to show the entire report with in single page without having to click next page button. I tried increasing page size but that doesnot work. Please help! I am new to Report Builder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the **InteractiveSize** -> **Height** property to `0cm`:

[image]

This will prevent implicit page breaks when viewed in Report Manager or a ReportViewer control.

This won't have any effect on printing, exporting to PDF, etc, as these media have to force page breaks no matter what - they're affected by the PageSize properties.